# Optimized logic in an if....else condition

Tags: c#, .net

Does anybody have an optimized logic for following if...else condition.....

**Scenario**

1. Three date parameters are there: DateFrom, DateUntil and NewDateUntil.
2. `If DateFrom <= DateNewUntil And DateUntil > NewDateUntil then` add a warning message and returns true
3. `If DateFrom > DateNewUntil And DateUntil > DateNewUntil then` add a warning message and returns false
4. `If DateUntil < DateNewUntil` then just `returns true`.

    Original code is commented below. Tried some optimization.
    Please have a look.

**Code**

```
public bool ValidateDate(DateTime pDateFrom, DateTime pDateUntil, DateTime pNewDateUntil)
{
  ////Original Code
  //if ((pDateUntil.Date > pNewDateUntil.Date))
  //{
  //  if ((pDateFrom.Date <= pNewDateUntil.Date))
  //  {
  //    pDateUntil = pNewDateUntil;
  //    AddWarningMessage("Warning Message");
  //    return true;
  //  }
  //  else if ((pDateFrom.Date > pNewDateUntil.Date))
  //  {
  //    AddWarningMessage("Warning Message");
  //    return false;
  //  }
  //}
  //else
  //{
  //  return true;
  //}

  //Optimized As:
  bool returnValue = false;
  if ((pDateUntil > pNewDateUntil.Date))
  {
    returnValue = pDateFrom <= pNewDateUntil.Date ? true : false;
    AddWarningMessage("Warning Message");
  }
  else
  {
    returnValue = true;
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'optimised logic'?

Comment: You can remove `? true : false` by the way. (that doesn't optimize it, but it does make it less weird)

Comment: Sometime is better not to optimize and sacrifice the readability.  I find this particulary true for date logic as yours

Comment: 1. Is it really the same `"Warning Message"` in both cases? 2. Do you really start all parameter names with `p`!?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: just looking for a better/simple logic to reduce the if else conditions to its minimum.

Comment: Also, your original code doesn't compile: *"not all code paths return a value"*

Comment: @Kobi: 1. 'message' is same in both situations. 2. Is that wrong....? or..do we have any other standards...Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you should do:

```
bool returnValue = pDateUntil <= pNewDateUntil.Date || pDateFrom <= pNewDateUntil.Date;
if ((pDateUntil > pNewDateUntil.Date))
{
    AddWarningMessage("Warning Message");
}
return returnValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Resharper is telling me you can do the following:

```
bool returnValue;
if ((pDateUntil > pNewDateUntil.Date))
{
    returnValue = pDateFrom <= pNewDateUntil.Date;
    AddWarningMessage("Warning Message");
}
else
{
    returnValue = true;
}
return returnValue;
```

Comment: Did Resharper alse delete `AddWarningMessage("Warning Message");` ??

Comment: You could also inline `returnValue`.

Comment: @Ken, We cannot remove AddWarningMessage("Warning Message"); line. But thanks.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the line back in... Did so for testing purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do only few things about it. You should "sort" your if statements and start from the most probably one. Note, that the compiler usually optimizes these situations very well, and there is also the Branch Prediction which helps.

```
  if (condition_is_true_the_most often)
  {
      // your code here
  }
  else if (condition_is_true_less_often)
  {
      // your code here
  }
  .
  .
  .
  else if (...)
  {
  }
```